# how to write the corresponding "handle_uploaded_file" for the model field and form?

Tags: django

```
attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='file/upload/question/%Y-%m-%d', verbose_name='attachment', null=True, blank=True,)

def handle_uploaded_file (file_, user):
    filename = "%s-%s" % (user.username , file_.name)
    path = "%s/file/upload/question/%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, user.username, filename)
    if not os.path.exists (path): 
        os.makedirs(path)
    f = path + file.name
    fd = open(f, 'wb+')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.close()
```

***i don't know how to write the path and the following code?***

```
def submit_question(request):
    current_user = request.user
    url = '/question/list_questions/'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['attachment'], current_user)  

            new_question = Question(question = form.cleaned_data['question'],
                                    question_type= form.cleaned_data['question_type'],
                                    country = form.cleaned_data['country'], 
                                    submitter = form.cleaned_data['submitter'],
                                    is_private = form.cleaned_data['is_private'],
                                    #attachment = temp_attachment,
                                    )
            new_question.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    context = {'form': form,}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('question/submit.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to handle **file attachments** by yourself, django will do it for you.

[Properties of FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) is here. I uesd it a few times before, i can not remember exactly butusing something as following must do the job...

First, create your form from related model:

```
class SomeFormWithFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
```

then in your view, where you create your form instance,

```
form = SomeFormWithFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

will do the trick.

Comment: yes, that's the way. it is good to use. in fact i really want to customize the pathname for the file not just by date as the doc tells.

Comment: In this case, the document saved in which location?

Comment: I mean is there any location that I can see my document is really saved? Because I need to handle the doc so that I will send the doc to someone else by an email.

Comment: I fix the link and set it to the development version of django docs. If you are using FileSystemStorage (or an older version of django where there is no Storage type option available in `settings.py`),  it will be saved to your `MEDIA_ROOT` loacation defined in your `settings.py` file. If you specify `uplaod_to` parameter in `Model.FileField` then it will be in there under  `MEDIA_ROOT`